# Resizable column in material-table react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

I have been working on material-table for quite a while and I have looked for different options where I can provide functionality of drag the column to adjust width but to no success.

I googled quite a lot on how I can achieve this functionality in react but to no success.

I was able to find other tables but all my modules are built on material-table.

[Drag and drop table in angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtfc5v)

I have provided link for drag and drop in angular but I'm working on react and I couldn't find any thing on material-table for react.

There is no code included here, as I couldn't find anything on it. Only static widths are available as it was no use for this condition.

Let me know on how can I incorporate provided example into react or if there is any working example or whether it is possible or not.

So I found in their GitHub page there is a mention of resizable column by selecting true in options, but its not working for me yet.

[Resizable column material table official merial-table github](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/demo/demo.js)

Comment: Material-table does not provide option to make column widths resizable out of the box.

Comment: So is there any way where I can achieve this. Any thing that you could suggest.

Also there is mention of columnResizable in their github - demo, do you have any idea what it does?

Comment: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/column-resizing you can check this react table is another option you can choose.

Answer (score 0):

Material-table does now provide this capability.  You need to use the following two options:

- tableLayout of 'fixed', as need to turn off the default auto width setting
- columnResizable of true

from demo.js under demo directory in material-table

```
<MaterialTable
  ...
  options={{
    tableLayout: "fixed",
    columnResizable: true
  }}
/>
```

In current implementation you can shrink the column so you lose the ability to further change the columns width.

Comment: This does not work for me. What version of material table provides this?

Comment: I was in material-table before development stopped.  Fortunately improvements have carried on in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-table/core and these improvements include better column resizing.

See demo see Resizable() in https://github.com/material-table-core/core/blob/master/__tests__/demo/demo-components/index.js 

If you still have problems then please post details of the version you're using and the material table options